# Dir command with creation time and last modified time

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I want to use dir command and have filename as 1st column, creation date time as 2nd column and modified date time as 3rd column.

How could I achieve this?

http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm

This shows `/T` might be used but not sure how to use it because `dir /TCAW` doesn't list the format I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Christopher Painter says, the DIR command cannot do this directly.

But there is a simple command line one liner that displays your information without header or footer info. This command lists only files. It works as long as your locality displays time stamps using 3 space delimited components. For example, my U.S. time stamps display as `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am`.

```
for /f "tokens=1-4*" %A in ('dir /a-d /tc^|findstr "^[0-9]"') do @echo %E  %A %B %C  %~tE
```

Change `/a-d` to `/a` if you want to include directories. Or simply remove `/a-d` entirely if you want both files and directories but you want to exclude hidden and system files/directories.

Here is the same command in a nicely formatted batch script:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-4*" %%A in (
  'dir /a-d /tc^|findstr "^[0-9]"'
) do echo %%E  %%A %%B %%C  %%~tE
```

I don't like the output format with the file name in the front because the width of the name varies - it is hard to read the output because the columns don't line up. I prefer to put the file name at the end:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-4*" %%A in (
  'dir /a-d /tc^|findstr "^[0-9]"'
) do echo %%A %%B %%C  %%~tE  %%E
```

Comment: Why? :)  Seriously.. it's a good thought exercise (+1 for that) but .bat scripting has no purpose in the year 2014.  If one really wants to write scripting on the Windows platform they should be looking at PowerShell.

Comment: You are a super guy with multi talented abilities like playing flute :) Although this is way too slow it serves exactly what I need. Could you please explain what are these cryptic %%A, %%B and so on?

Answer (score 3):

DIR doesn't support what you are trying to do.  the /T:Fileld ID can only show one set of time information at a time.   I'm not sure what you are trying to do but I see you have some C# experience.  You could write your only console app that outputs the way you out and call that instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ ECHO OFF 

(FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d') DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1-3*" %%x IN ('dir /a-d /tc "%%~a"^|findstr "^[0-9]"') DO (
        ECHO "%%a",%%~ta,%%x %%y %%z
    )
)) > DIR.txt

TYPE DIR.txt
```

the answer in refered to : [Windows batch file to create csv list of file and dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086487/windows-batch-file-to-create-csv-list-of-file-and-dates)