# Windows CLI list requirement: dir /n/s list, but one line per file dir /b/s and with inline full path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting, file-search

I frequently use a batchscript dirlist.bat to generate a quick searchable text to find file information.

dirlist.bat

```
dir *.* /b/s >dirlist.txt
```

now I need additionally date and size information. As this would build a multicolumn  list a csv-listoutput would be prefered.

This is my inspiration:

```
dir *.doc? /n/s >dirlist.txt
```

but I get a mixed multiline output. Filematches and folder summaries are intermingled.

Do you know a script approch to list the base information of each filematch into one line?

Comment: You'd probably be better off using PowerShell rather than doing Unix-style text-mangling

Comment: Can you be more specific, giving a code example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch file to create csv list of file and dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086487/windows-batch-file-to-create-csv-list-of-file-and-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use `ForFiles`.

Example:

```bat
@(ForFiles /S /M *.* /C "Cmd /C Echo @File,@FDate,@FSize")>DirList.txt
```

Comment: Many thanks. This works like a charm. Here some slight modifications, using ";" as CSV-separator for my resident country:  @(ForFiles /S /M *.* /C "Cmd /C Echo @FDate;@fsize;@file;@path;")>DirList.csv

Comment: I hadn't noticed that my autocorrect had removed the `F`, code corrected, thanks. I have not replaced the commas because the question is related to a `CSV`, _and guess what the `C` stands for?_

Answer (score 1):

Why not just run a loop and get the date and filesize with it?

```
for /f %i in ('dir /b/s *.doc?') do echo %~zti %~dpfi >>dirlist.txt
```

you can dump the `dir` command and simply use the `for /d` and `/r` (recursive) search. See `for /?`